# Cannot print colored text on Windows

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, trying to print a colored text in the console. My OS is windows 10. Here is the code:

```
class bcolors:
    """
    Colors for console
    """
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    YGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'

def main():
    user_name: str = input(
        f'***Hello {bcolors.YGREEN}friend{bcolors.ENDC} Welcome***\nPlease enter your Name:\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but when I execute this code either through CMD or PyCharm, I don't get colored text. Here is the output:

[image: pic]

What's wrong?

Comment: What OS are you on? What terminal emulator?

Comment: @RayWu I added the details.

Comment: This code only works on an XTerm-compliant Linux/Unix terminal. If you would like this code to work, see https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code only works on an XTerm-compliant Linux/Unix terminal. If you would like this code to work, see https://pypi.org/project/colorama.

```
import colorama
colorama.init(wrap=True)

class bcolors:
    """
    Colors for console
    """
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    YGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'

def main():
    print(f'***Hello {bcolors.YGREEN}friend{bcolors.ENDC} Welcome***\nPlease enter your Name:\n', end='')
    user_name: str = input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code works on XTerm-compliant Linux/Unix terminal, yes?

Comment: Yes, and also Windows!
You just need the `import colorama` and `colorama.init()`

Comment: It didn't work on Windows executing through CMD and PyCharm.

Comment: What did you get? I need more information than "it didn't work". Did you get the same output as in the question? Did you install the module with `pip`?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the package, and I get the same output that I mentioned in my post.

Comment: No and here is the output: `<colorama.ansitowin32.AnsiToWin32 object at 0x0000018AF6144C08>`

Comment: I have fixed it. Colorama only works with print() and not input().

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use [Printy](https://github.com/edraobdu/printy) instead:

Install:

`pip3 install printy`

Use it:

```
from printy import inputy

user_name = inputy("Hello [n]friend@, \n Please enter your name:)
```

the 'n' flag will apply a green color to the word friend. It is an OS independent library

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in your main: 
`print(bcolors.WARNING + "Warning: No active frommets remain. Continue?" + bcolors.ENDC)`
Or this:
    `print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}Warning: No active frommets remain. Continue?{bcolors.ENDC}")`

Comment: The OP has stated that they are on Windows, presumably using a terminal that doesn't support these ANSI escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not installing anything, simply add this to the start of your code

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use os as well :)

Here a solution works on Windows

this solution works in cmd, powershell

```py
#first import os
import os
# make printing colors possible
os.system('')
# get an amzing reuslt :D
# '\033[44m' is the color
print('\033[44m'+'Test'+'\033[0m') # '\033[0m' the end of the color
```

I test it and it works perfectly

```py
python -c "import os;os.system('');print('\033[34m'+'Test'+'\033[0m')"
```

[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U02zx.png)

thanks to [SimpleBinary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54955094/19313724) for forging out.

if you don't want to write this code then you can use cmder

cmder allowed you to use colors without `os.system()'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).