# How to color text in python .exe?

Tags: python

I use the following code to make the text colored: `stopLoss = float(input(colored("Enter stop loss price> ", 'red')))`. It works well wihtin Pycharm, but when I convert the python file to .exe file using pyinstaller, it outputs this: `←[31mEnter stop loss price> ←[0m20`. What should I do?

Comment: Answers are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61701889/cannot-print-colored-text-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot print colored text on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61701889/cannot-print-colored-text-on-windows)

Comment: use colorama to change the color

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use:

```
import os 

os.system('color 04') #red foreground color
```

color command syntax is: `color *background* *foreground*`

Here are the color codes

0 = Black
8 = Gray

1 = Blue
9 = Light Blue

2 = Green
A = Light Green

3 = Aqua
B = Light Aqua

4 = Red
C = Light Red

5 = Purple
D = Light Purple

6 = Yellow
E = Light Yellow

7 = White
F = Bright White

Answer (score 0):

You can try colorama.

```py
import colorama

colorama.init(True) # You dont need True, its so that you dont need to reset
# Text color after sending color all the time.

print(colorama.Fore.RED + "Hi!")
```

Would result in "Hi!" being printed as red color.

`UPDATE:`You also need to install it, you can do so by:
`pip install colorama` (Might change from OS to OS.)